# Vaadin ConfirmDialog - set focus to Cancel button

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Using Vaadin Flow [Confirm Dialog](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/confirm-dialog) I'm creating a dialog like below:

```java
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog(
    "Delete Person",
    "Do you really want to delete Person?",
    "Delete",
    deleteEvent -> { Notification.show("Delete was clicked");},
    "Cancel",
    cancelEvent -> { Notification.show("Cancel was clicked");}
);
```

[image]

Since this is a **destructive action**, it is important that the initial focus is not on the
Delete button, for example if user simply hits the Enter key. How can it be achieved that the initial focus is on the Cancel button?

### MarcusHellberg suggestion for solution

The idea is to swap the actions. Like this:

```java
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog(
    "Delete Person",
    "Do you really want to delete Person?",
    "Cancel",
    cancelEvent -> { Notification.show("Cancel was clicked");},
    "Delete",
    deleteEvent -> { Notification.show("Delete was clicked");}
);
// We need to re-style the buttons:
dialog.setCancelButtonTheme(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY.getVariantName());    // Style the "Confirm" button
dialog.setConfirmButtonTheme(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY.getVariantName());  // Style the "Cancel" button
```

[image]

As can be seen it creates a different user experience where the primary action is now on the left.
Also, for the developer, it gets kind of confusing because developer has to remember that all actions are opposite, so for example calling method `addCancelListener()` actually refers to the Confirm action and vice versa. Very dangerous if developer forgets.

Comment: Have you considered swapping your actions? So that the primary button is Cancel and the secondary action is Delete. To me that would feel more appropriate than focusing the secondary action by default.

Comment: @MarcusHellberg. No I haven't. But I have tested it out now and added it to the question. It is not a solution I like, I'm afraid. I've been toying with having Cancel Button as a component (the API for ConfirmDialog allows this) and then calling `btnCancel.focus()`, but I cannot make it work. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: would you consider disabling the enter key via javascript? or intercept that keypress event and close the modal?

Comment: Instead of using the pre-build component that doesn't fit your needs, you can also use the Dialog and build it like you need it. There you can also listen for an open event to focus the button you want.